# What distinguishes logical necessity, logical consequence, logical truth, and tautology from one another?

Tags: logic, truth, tautology

The text I'm reading distinguishes *logical necessity*, *logical consequence*, *logical truth*, and *tautology* from one another; however it doesn't make their distinctions especially perspicuous.

As far as I interpreted it,

- Logical consequence: truth of the antecedent or premises guarantees the truth of the consequent or conclusions.
- Logical truth: Any statement that must be valuated true, even if the set of premises is the empty set. (3=3, p v ~p, etc)
- Tautology: Any statement that must be valuated true, but only when the statement is stated.  (as opposed to logical truths)
- Logical necessity: for any set of statements containing the logically necessary statement in question, the logically necessary statement can be evaluated as true under at least one valuation.

Comment: You can see in *SEP* the following entries : [Logical Truth](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-truth/) and [Logical Consequence](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-consequence/). *Tautology* is a technical term (in *propositional logic*) without "philosophical" connotations. *Logical consequence* is a technical term **with** "philosophical" connotations. *Logical truth* may be equated with *validity*, and so is a technical term, but has some deep aspects and implications. *Logical necessity* involves modal logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tautologies are logical truths in the context of propositional logic:

> φ is a tautology       =<sub>def</sub>   φ is assigned ⊤ by all rows of the truth-table for φ.

Logical truths are something more general, and can be defined as follows:

> φ is a logical truth   =<sub>def</sub>   a true interpretation of the *logical constants* occurring in φ makes φ true.

Logical consequence is similar to that:

> φ is a logical consequence of ψ   =<sub>def</sub>   every true interpretation of ψ makes φ true.

Logical necessity is a modal notion, and can be defined using state-descriptions:

> φ is logically necessary   =<sub>def</sub>    φ is true in all state-descriptions.

All of these definitions are *inspired* by Carnap, but may differ from his actual definitions.